# Dialog display in Dojo

Tags: dojo, dialog, screen

How to unblock the screen when a dialog being displayed?

Usually when a dialog appears underlay(screen) is blocked and gets grey coloured. But i need to provide access to underlay even a dialog appears. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do that is to hide the underlay using css. Dojo will always give the underlay the same id as the dialog followed by `_underlay`. So if your dialog has the id `myDialog` then just add the following css somewhere:

```
#myDialog_underlay {
    display: none;
}
```

More info can be found at http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Dialog

Comment: But if i create the dialog programmatically in a js file how to incorporate this style?

Comment: @John: I think you can get the id through myDialog.id or myDialog.domNode.id

Comment: Well I would suggest that you control what the id is gonna be by either setting it manually or placing the Dialog in a predefined div with the id you want to use.